# add Lucene PorterStemmer into MLlib pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, lucene, nlp, token, pipeline

I am trying to write a pipe using spark.ml.feature, basically tokenizer, stopwords, and stemmer. Because spark doesn't have stemmer, I plan to add Lucene's. My two questions are:

1) Can anyone show me the syntax for Lucene stemmer pipeline? I found one which must put in an argument PorterStemFilter(TokenStream in). But this doesn't fit into pipeline (without any arguments yet).

2) Is Lucene's API fully compatible with spark's

Comment: There is one for snowball stemmer (not lucene PorterStemmer you are looking for) that fits into spark ml pipeline https://github.com/master/spark-stemming